# If element contains h1, remove h1 from another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to dynamically remove an h1 from a page if the h1 is already used in another area on the same page. For example, if the h1 is in a banner along the top of a page, it won't be needed in any area underneath on the same page.

```
    <div class="banner">
    <h1>Check to see if title here</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="rest_of_page">
    <h1>Remove this h1 if the above h1 exists already</h1>
    </div>
```

Tried a couple of things but they seem to remove both h1 tags and not just the bottom one should the top one exist. There may be some pages where the banner isn't used, so the h1 underneath will need to stay.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We do like to see code and effort so please update the question with what you tried that did not work. A `<>` snippet is even better

Comment: How should we know which `h1` should stay ?

Comment: @weedoze:  _if the h1 is in a banner along the top of a page, it won't be needed in any area underneath on the same page._

Comment: @mplungjan This was used as an example. The main sentence is **I'm trying to dynamically remove an h1 from a page if the h1 is already used in another area on the same page**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle the second banner:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#rest_of_page>h1").toggle(
    $(".banner>h1").length==0
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner">
  <h1>Check to see if title here</h1>
</div>

<div id="rest_of_page">
  <h1>Remove this h1 if the above h1 exists already</h1>
</div>
```

Or remove it

```js
$(function() {
  if ($(".banner>h1").length>0) $("#rest_of_page>h1").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner">
  <h1>Check to see if title here</h1>
</div>

<div id="rest_of_page">
  <h1>Remove this h1 if the above h1 exists already</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using vanilla js - 
first get all the h1 using querySelectAll,
if its more than 1 h1, iterate over the h1 array and remove evrey h1 but the first.

```
var h1 = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
if (h1.length > 1) {
    for (var i=1; i< h1.lenght; i++){
        h1[i].parentElement.removeChild(h1[i])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = $('.banner').find('h1'); // or other container... 
if (element.length) $('h1').not(element).remove();
```

Comment: `element.length` should return n or 0 if not... I edited my post, my jQuery is old, sry!

Answer (score 0):

this is fairly easy. You have to look for an element using `.find()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.banner').find('h1').length > 0) {
        $('.rest_of_page').find('h1').remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First check the length of jQuery object `$('.banner h1').length`, if it is true then remove all the remaining `h1` with the following code:

```
heading = $('.banner h1');

if(heading.length) {
  $('h1').not(heading).remove();
}
```

```js
heading = $('.banner h1');

if(heading.length) {
  $('h1').not(heading).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner">
  <h1>Check to see if title here</h1>
</div>

<div id="rest_of_page">
  <h1>Remove this h1 if the above h1 exists already</h1>
</div>
<h1>Remove this h1 if the above h1 exists already</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to retrieve all `H1` nodes and iterate through them, removing all except the first one. This works, because `jQuery` returns the matched elements in *document order* (aka from top to bottom).

```
$("h1").each(function(index, elem) {
  if (index > 0) {
    $(elem).remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*solution without jQuery*

You can query each h1 element by tag with `document.getElementsByTagName('h1')` and then remove every element after the first with `remove`.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
Object.keys(elems).forEach(function(key, i) {
  if (i > 0) {
    elems[key].remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a jquery code which can resolve your issue if you come through the above situation that you mentioned.

```
$("h1")[$("h1").length-1].remove();
```

To remove multiple h1 element present in the page except the first one, you can use below jquery code.

```
 $("h1").each(function(e){
    if(e>0){         
        $(this).remove();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.has()` in jquery. if you add dom contents dynamically means you need to traverse from the top of the dom elements.

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant
>   that matches the selector or DOM element.

```js
$('.banner').has('h1').parents('body').find('h1:not(.banner h1)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner">
    <h1>Check to see if title here</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="rest_of_page">
    <h1>Remove this h1 if the above h1 exists already</h1>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  var cnt=0;
  $('h1').replaceWith(function(){
      if (cnt++)
        return $("<div>").append($(this).contents());
      else
        return $("<h1>").append($(this).contents());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <h1>header1</h1> 
  <h1>header2</h1> 
  <h1>header3</h1>
```